# Switch statement not properly functioning

Tags: android, onclick

The goal here is to sense when a certain view is clicked (by ID name identified by the specific button that is clicked) and then trigger an action in an instance of another class.

I'm not 100% sure that it is reading correctly. I'll post the code and then explain the issue afterwards.

In Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Set starting player to 1 or 0
        if( mGame.getPlayerCounter() == 0 ) {
            mGame.determineStartingPlayer();
        }

        //Fills buttons on mGame instance 
        fillButtonSpaces(v);
        ....

//Check if the board has to be reset for either a tie or a win 
        if(mGame.checkGameTie() || mGame.checkGameWinner()) { 
            //Resets java mGame board logic 
            mGame.resetGameBoard();

             //Reset the physical GUI gameboard 
            resetPhysicalGameBoard();
        }}

public void fillButtonSpaces(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.imageButtonOne :
              mGame.fillSquareZero();
       case R.id.imageButtonTwo :
              mGame.fillSquareOne();
       case R.id.imageButtonThree :
              mGame.fillSquareTwo();
       case R.id.imageButtonFour :
              mGame.fillSquareThree();
       case R.id.imageButtonFive :
              mGame.fillSquareFour();
       case R.id.imageButtonSix :
              mGame.fillSquareFive();
       case R.id.imageButtonSeven :
              mGame.fillSquareSix();
       case R.id.imageButtonEight :
              mGame.fillSquareSeven();
       case R.id.imageButtonNine :
              mGame.fillSquareEight();
     }
}
```

Then in another class:

```
public void fillSquareZero() {
    if( getCurrentPlayer() == 0) {
        spaceZero = 0; } else {
            spaceZero = 1;
        }
}

public void fillSquareOne() {
    if( getCurrentPlayer() == 0) {
        spaceOne = 0; } else {
            spaceOne = 1;
        }
}

public void fillSquareTwo() {
    if( getCurrentPlayer() == 0) {
        spaceTwo = 0; } else {
            spaceTwo = 1;
        }
}
.... etc.....
```

These methods should be called to set values for the game board to either 1 or 0. I then want to check this method (as called on each onclick to see if there is a winner)

```
public boolean checkGameWinner() {
    //Player 1 (Human) player winning rules
    if (spaceZero == 0 && spaceOne == 0 && spaceTwo == 0) {
        return true;
        }
```

So based on which button is clicked (figured in the switch case), the mGame instance is setting the spaceZero - spaceEight variables to either 1 or 0 in the second class. So I'm checking to see if the first 3 are set to 0 (Player 1 has selected them). When I do this I'm not getting the desired result, the board is CLEARED whenever I hit the first cell if it's the player 1 bitmap being put there... Whats going on here?

Comment: You might want to "break" your switch cases

Comment: Alright sounds good- Thanks for the info Mike!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch case is missing a `break;` after each and every case. it should be

```
 switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.imageButtonOne :
              mGame.fillSquareZero();
              break;
       case R.id.imageButtonTwo :
              mGame.fillSquareOne();
              break;
       case R.id.imageButtonThree :
              mGame.fillSquareTwo();
              break;
```

etc...

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you very much man! It's always something so simple haha... Haven't used many switched cases. Much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the "break" statement at the end of each "case" clause.

This way, if you click R.id.imageButtonOne, the code `mGame.fillSquareZero();` gets executed, but so do other clauses for other cases.

More information on switch statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html